# Is there a way to store long html script in an html object

Tags: html

I am making a call to the database which returns some html scripts. 
Is there a way for an html tag (like an input tag) to hold these html scripts in its 'id' or 'value' without rendering the html on the page?

Comment: Why exactly would you want to include HTML that will not be rendered in a page? If it is for later use the correct way to send it would be an asynchronous request only if needed.

Comment: I query the database to get the long-html tag in asp while i'm creating a table. I later use that data in a javascript function

Answer (score 0):

Sure just encode it and add it to a data attribute of an existing element in the DOM.

Original HTML string: `​<strong><a href="http://www.google.com">Google Search</a></strong>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

could easily be converted into html entities and escaped with ASP and stored like this:

```
<input id="foo" value="bar" data-html="&lt;strong&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http:\/\/www.google.com&quot;&gt;Google Search&lt;\/a&gt;&lt;\/strong&gt;" />
```

Comment: would this work if i stored the Original HTML string in the data-html property directly (with the tags how they are)?

Comment: Yes but it's much easier to slip in a quote which would close your `data-html` attribute quote early. If nothing else, escape those.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's data function

```
$("#myInput").data("long-html", "your_data_here");
```

Comment: is there a way to do this using classic asp? I'm generating a table with other data on the fly and would like to put the long-html in a tag while the table is being created so that i can access it later

Answer (score 0):

You could base64 encode the HTML and then decode it when you need it